# Dynamic Price Changes in WooCommerce based on Country

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

This may not be a feature of WooCommerce but am hoping there's a work around :-)

Is it possible to have a product price that updates based on the users selected country? It doens't have to change currency, just the product price:

[image]

So not the shipping price, which would always remain the same, but rather the actual product price dynamically updated when the user selects their country from the drop down

I managed to find a plugin that gets close but no cigar, namely it only updates prices based on the users browser settings 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocomerce-price-by-country/

Equally, the native Flat Rate Shipping doesn't seem to offer this functionality.

Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Woocommerce - Product price depending on country](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863612/woocommerce-product-price-depending-on-country)

Answer (score 2):

Woocommerce price by country has a country select add on, in the FAQ

"You can add a country selector somewhere template
Yes, adding "do_action('get_pbc_country_dropdown')"; .
"

Also, multi language woo commerce has a feature that i think would work for you, it has multiple currency support as well as the ability to change prices for different territories that you configure, and a shortcode for a dropdown currency changer

http://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/woocommerce-multilingual/multi-currency-support-woocommerce/

Comment: WooCommerce Multilingual & Multicurrency with WPML (Works) great fix - https://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/woocommerce-multilingual/multi-currency-support-woocommerce/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this plugin:

WooCommerce Price Based on Country

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-price-based-on-countries/

When country changes on checkout page, the cart, the order preview and all shop are updated to display the correct currency and pricing.

**Multicurrency**
Sell and receive payments in different currencies, reducing the costs of currency conversions.

**Country Switcher**
The extension include a country switcher widget to allow your customer change the country from the frontend of your website.

**Adding a country selector to the front-end**
Once you’ve added support for multiple country and their currencies, you could display a country selector in the theme. You can display the country selector with a shortcode or as a hook.

**Shortcode**

[wcpbc_country_selector]

**PHP Code**

do_action('wcpbc_manual_country_selector');