# Variable product price not showing in listing and details page WooCommerce Price Based on Country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price

When the product is listed in Product listing page or Product details page, The price not showing.When I click on any variation like color,then only the product price is displayed.If I deactivate the plug-in its all works good.

Note:  I am using

1. Wordpress-4.6.1
2. WooCommerce Price Based on Country Version 1.6.2 | By Oscar Gare
3. WooCommerce Version 2.6.7.

All the products are variable products(color).
I surfed on net for this and found something like this
*[Woocommerce - Product price depending on country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863612/woocommerce-product-price-depending-on-country) which is not useful for me.Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why dont you ask for support directly in the author support pages of **WooCommerce Price Based on Country** plugin , as it looks like a bug in this plugin.

Comment: Thanks bro.But I already did that.No reply yet.I am out of time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a temporary solution for this problem.Just go to edit product page in wordpress back-end and simply edit something and update the product.My suggestion is Please go for other plugins to "Change the price based on country" option.